# Regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

We want to do find and replace using preg_replace . But unable to get the desired result

here is my string

```
    $x = '<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/2005/11/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>';
    $x .= '<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/2005/10/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>';
    $x .= '<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/20>';05/1/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>';
    $x .= '<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/2005/9/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>';
    $x .= '<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/2006/11/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>';
    $x .= '<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a

    echo preg_replace('/<a(.*?)href="http:\/\/atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com\/atlas_shrugs\/([0-9\/]{0,7}?)(.*?)_.html#(.*?)"(.*?)>/','<a$1href="http://localhost/test/$3#$4"$5>',$x);
```

Its gives the following result

```
<a href="http://localhost/test/2005/11/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>
<a href="http://localhost/test/2005/10/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>
<a href="http://localhost/test/2005/1/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>
<a href="http://localhost/test/2005/9/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>
<a href="http://localhost/test/2006/11/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>
<a href="http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>
```

But we want result like

```
<a href="http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>
<a href="http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>
<a href="http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>
<a href="http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>
<a href="http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>
<a href="http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried using [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) instead of regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

If we start by side lining your current regex pattern...

This:

```
$x = '<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/2005/11/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657410">FALLACI</a>';
$x .= '<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/2005/10/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657411">FALLACI</a>';
$x .= '<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/2005/1/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657412">FALLACI</a>';
$x .= '<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/2005/9/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657413">FALLACI</a>';
$x .= '<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/2006/11/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657414">FALLACI</a>';
$x .= '<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657415">FALLACI</a>';

echo preg_replace('~<a.*?href=["\'].*?/([^/]*?)_\.html#(.*?)["\'].*?>(.*?)</a>~', "<a href='http://localhost/test/$1#$2'>$3</a><br>\n", $x);
```

Outputs:

```
<a href='http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657410'>FALLACI</a><br>
<a href='http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657411'>FALLACI</a><br>
<a href='http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657412'>FALLACI</a><br>
<a href='http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657413'>FALLACI</a><br>
<a href='http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657414'>FALLACI</a><br>
<a href='http://localhost/test/i_leave_shreds#comment-11657415'>FALLACI</a><br>
```

#### Regex Explanation

```
~<a.*?href=["'].*?/([^/]*?)_\.html#(.*?)["'].*?>(.*?)</a>~
```

- `~` = Starting delimeter
- `<a.*?` = matches the opening `a` tag followed by any character 0 or more times until it reaches...
- `href=["']` = matches `href=` followed by either `"` or `'`
- `.*?/` = matches all characters until the final slash before...
- `([^/]*?)` = capture group and catches everything between the final slash and...
- `_\.html#` = matches the underscore and `html` file extension of the url followed by a `#`
- `(.*?)` = capture group matches all characters (the comment/number) before...
- `["'].*?>` = matches either `"` or `'` followed by any charachter 0 or more times until it reaches the end of the opening `a` tag: `>`
- `(.*?)` = matches the text between the opening and closing `a` tags: `FALLACI`
- `</a>` = matches the closing `a` tag

### Update

To limit the replacements to only those containing: `atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com` you can update the regex to:

```
~<a.*?href=["\'].*?atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com.*?/([^/]*?)_\.html#(.*?)["\'].*?>(.*?)</a>~
```

The difference between this regex and the original is (line 4 of the bullet-point list above):

```
.*?/                                <-- Original
.*?atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com.*?/  <-- Updated
```

Simply the updated version checks for any characters (e.g. `http://`) before the specific URL `atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com` followed by any characters after it.

Examples of matches (http/https/BLANK):

```
<a href="http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/2005/11/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657410">FALLACI</a>
<a href="atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/2005/11/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657410">FALLACI</a>
<a href="https://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com/atlas_shrugs/2005/11/i_leave_shreds_.html#comment-11657410">FALLACI</a>
```

Comment: If there is another url in href then it should not be replaced. We want to replace only if href contain this url "http://atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com".

Comment: Okay, I have updated the answer with a more specific regex pattern and explanation...

Comment: Thanks you very much for the precious help .
Can you suggest me a link where i could study about regex.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ click on `Tutorial` located in the _top bar_ menu there's explanations about just about everything to do with regex :)

Comment: Although its working fine when the data is few. But when we performing the same in database file it gives the memory size error. What is the best way to do the same in database file. Thanks

Comment: What is the size of your database file?

Comment: file size is 325MB. and memory_limit in php_ini is 2024MB

Comment: and what is the file type?

Comment: I was using file_get_contents with a sql file. however, reading file line by line solved the memory issue.

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion, glad to hear you got it worked out :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here: `([0-9\/]{0,7}?)`... you've got 0-7 instances, and then you want to get as few of those as possible. you don't need to specify both... remove the ? at the end (so it looks like `([0-9\/]{0,7})` ) and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
`/<a(.*?)href="http:\/\/atlasshrugs2000.typepad.com\/atlas_shrugs\/([0-9\/]{0,7})\/(.*?)_.html#(.*?)"(.*?)>/` 
change `{0,7}?)(` to `{0,7})\/(`